# Neural networks: Getting the equivalent of an SAS “iteration plot” with R?

Tags: r, plot, neural-network

With SAS, you get an iteration plot when you generate a neural network. The plot shows how the error changes between the training and validation data for each iteration, and the point where the algorithm has chosen the optimal stopping point (to maximize generalization) is shown. How do you get a plot like this with R?

With the R neuralnet package, you can define stepmax to limit the number of steps per repetition. Do you have use stepmax in a loop to produce a meaningful graph? For example, if you predetermine that the network trains in 750 steps in 1 repetition, you could start with 650 steps (stepmax), then 660, ..., 850. This is using a for loop than adds 10 to stepmax each time. You then plot the errors. I assume this would work. Is there a better way? Is there a different neural net function that will give you this information directly?

I would like a loss vs. epoch plot, and an accuracy vs. epoch plot (with training and validation accuracy).   If I lower stepmax the algorithm doesn't converge, and it doesn't assign weights, so how can I get these plots?  With my model the algorithm ran for 52,000 steps. If I increase rep above 1, it has no effect on the model.

With no plots like these, how do we know the model will generalize well?

Comment: Which neural net package are you using?  `nnet`? `neuralnet`?  something else?

Comment: I'll use any package that will do a basic multilayer perceptron with one hidden layer.  I specified "neuralnet" (the package and function) because that is what I have used before.